# Convert exported Trello JSON to Pivotal Tracker CSV?

Tags: trello, import, export, file-conversion, pivotal-tracker

I am exporting a board from Trello, to import it into Pivotal Tracker. In order to get the full detail out of Trello, it's necessary to export as JSON. In order to import that detail into Pivotal Tracker, it's necessary to apply logic using some intermediary software:

- Descriptions include links to the original Trello card attachments, and links back to the original Trello tickets.
- Tasks based on the original Trello card checklists, and task status from the state of each original checklist item
- Labels based on the original Trello card labels
- Current State based on what list the original Trello card was in, e.g.:

  - Trello card was in "done" or "released" list -- Pivotal issue is Accepted
  - Trello card was in "review" list -- Pivotal issue is Delivered
  - Trello card was in "active" list -- Pivotal issue is Started
  - Trello card was in "ready" list -- Pivotal issue is Unstarted
  - Trello card was in "backlog" or "icebox" list -- Pivotal issue is Unscheduled
- Created At / Accepted At based on the current state to interpret original Trello card date 
  How can I convert a Trello .JSON file to a Pivotal Tracker .CSV file?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some software to run on my local computer, and convert a Trello JSON to a Pivotal Tracker CSV:

https://github.com/charneykaye/trello2pivotal

Clone that project to your computer. It's a [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) project. Before running, it's necessary to install Node packages:

```
npm install
```

Use it like this:

```
node main.js ~/Desktop/trello-xj-dev.json ~/Desktop/pivotal-tracker-xj-dev.csv
```

The file will be written to the target path, and the console will show info:

```
-=[ trello2pivotal ]=-

Did read 1551527 bytes from Trello .JSON file: /home/charney/Escritorio/trello-xj-dev.json

Did parse Trello board from JSON.

Trello Board Details:
  id: 584216b0f0e1aac6bff4cf36
  name: (xj) Dev
  desc: 
  idOrganization: 51cae57290af3e3e0b001662
  url: https://trello.com/b/qAcPeNUj/xj-dev
  memberships(2)
  shortLink: qAcPeNUj
  dateLastActivity: 2017-08-15T01:01:46.540Z
  dateLastView: 2017-08-15T02:00:55.013Z
  shortUrl: https://trello.com/b/qAcPeNUj
  actions(1000)
  cards(397)
  labels(8)
  lists(25)
  members(2)
  checklists(89)

Did cache 89 checklists.

Did cache 8 labels.

Did cache 25 lists.

Will allocate 31 Task/Status column pairs.

Will allocate 70 column names for CSV file.

Wrote 397 rows to CSV file.
```

Comment: The software you wrote works impressively well, especially given it's age. Nice work, and thank you.

Comment: Cheers @BillHorvath good to hear it is still useful